# Convert crosstab data into stacked table using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, stack

Input
[image]

Output Required
[image]

I tried df = df.stack() but its not showing date as separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your data to pandas dataframe (df) and use:

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'])
```

Comment: It says
KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['Date']"